# Запускать генерацию tt-шаблонов (t4) по кнопке / по команде

Tags: c#, t4

Не подскажите, пожалуйста, как обновлять / запускать генерацию кода из tt-шаблонов (t4) по кнопке/по команде?

- причем, хотелось, бы чтобы механизм обновления был привязан к solution-у (то есть, при открытии solution-а в другой студии на другой машине, чтобы механизм оставался рядом, чтобы можно было в любом случае по кнопке / по команде запустить генерацию, даже на другой машине, без предварительных <strike>настроек</strike>/установок [**upd**: зачеркнул вариант настроек, т.к. вариант с вызовом Custom Tool из студии, наверное, подходит, если этот tool с собой])
- генерация кода при билде - не совсем подходит, т.к. сама генерация может занимать там пол минуты (примерно, не суть), такая задержка при каждом билде не желательна, потому что генерация необходима, относительно редко
- есть вариант самостоятельного запуска `TextTransform.exe` как написано здесь ([Run T4 programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45885100/2772330)); но проблемка с этим вариантом в том, что кодогенерация использует `EnvDTE.DTE` (на сколько я понимаю, это объект самой вижуал-студии, с помощью которого можно, например, разбирать уже написанный код проекта); при вызове `TextTransform.exe` откуда-то не из студии, этот `EnvDTE.DTE` будет = null, и тогда не сработает код шаблона

```
    // UPD: код, который дает Null reference exception 
    // когда вызывал TextTransform.exe из своего консольного приложения
    var visualStudio 
        = (this.Host as IServiceProvider)
        .GetService(typeof(EnvDTE.DTE)) as EnvDTE.DTE;
```

- Всего таких шаблонов в solution-е несколько (скажем, 10, не суть); сейчас для обновления открываю каждый из шаблонов, добавляю пробел где-нибудь в комментарии (чтобы файл был измененным); при сохранении измененного файла вызывается кодогенерация. В принципе, такое решение приемлемо, но не красивое и не уверен, что коллеги одобрят
- **Upd** *(дополнительное пояснение)* **:** подразумевается, чтобы коллеги сами могли генерировать код и чтобы у них не возникло первым впечатлением, что что-то  не просто... Два интерфейса (`public interface IService` и `public interface IServiceCallback`) в одном проекте являются как бы моделью на основе которой генерируется код. Для коллег надо написать инструкцию, как редактировать эти интерфейсы, и как сделать, чтобы сгенерировался код. Будет симпатичнее, если в инструкции будет описана какая-то одна команда для обновления кода. Чтобы максимально упростить добавление кода.

Comment: Вы создали шаблон T4, сохранили - в этот момент был сгенерирован файл. Вы залили в систему контроля версий (github) свой код, не только T4, но и сгенерированный файл. Коллеги потом скачают ваш код уже вместе со сгенерированным файлом. Им незачем запускать шаблон.

Comment: _сейчас для обновления открываю каждый из шаблонов_ - ваш T4 генерирует код на основе другого кода (других файлов/сборок проекта)?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, спасибо! Да! Тут подразумевается, чтобы коллеги сами могли генерировать код и не ужаснуться от того как всё не просто... Два интерфейса (`public interface IService` и `public interface IServiceCallback`) в одном проекте являются как бы моделью на основе которой генерируется код. Для коллег надо написать инструкцию, как редактировать эти интерфейсы, и как сделать, чтобы сгенерировался код. Будет симпатичнее, если в инструкции будет описана какая-то одна команда для обновления кода. Чтобы максимально упростить добавление кода.

Comment: Единственный выход, который я вижу, использовать [TextTransform.exe](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/generating-files-with-the-texttransform-utility?view=vs-2019). Чтобы разработчики не путались, сделать скрипт на bat или powershell, выполлняющий трансформацию. Сам файл скрипта содержится в папке проекта (солюшена) и хранится в системе контроля версий, так что любой разраб всегда имеет его свежую версию.

Comment: Дополнительно можно добавить кнопку в меню Visual Studio: Tools > External Tools... > Add. Вписываем туда вызов TextTransform.exe. Но это, вероятно, каждый прогер должен сделать сам на своей машине.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, спасибо! Но, к сожалению, при вызове External Tool (`TextTransform.exe`), вижу, что повторяется та же ошибка, что и в 3-ем пункте пояснения вопроса....

Comment: Внезапно, Visual Studio уже имеет кнопку в меню Build > Transform All T4 Templates. Никогда раньше на неё внимания не обращал.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, Действительно, внезапно!.. Но приятно... Добавите ответ? Только, еще надо будет (либо вам либо мне) уточнить, эта фича любой студии, или, там, только для (например) про...

Comment: А по этой кнопке ваши шаблоны работают? У вас там что-то нестандартное с EnvDTE.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, эта функция - это на 100% то, что надо. Особенно порадует, если эта функция не только для специфичной студии, а для любой студии не зависимо от ее версии (pro / ultimate / community). Попробовал ее у себя и вижу, что файлы перегенерировались. Заняло ~30 секунд для 6-ти tt. В потенциале, могут быть еще новые tt для солшена. 30 лишних секунд ждать для каждого билда - не удобно, при том, что перегенерация актуальна достаточно редко. Спасибо, что написали! Напишите ответ, либо потом сам напишу.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, сам не нашел для какой студии эта фича (pro / ultimate / community). прошу прощения... думал, что поиск проще... но не важно...  и без этого ответ понятен, если у кого-то нет этого, то значит нет...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Внезапно оказалось, что в Visual Studio уже есть пункт в меню Build > Transform All T4 Templates. Он перегенерирует все файлы *.tt в проекте.

Этот пункт есть, по крайней мере в VS 2017 и VS 2019.
К сожалению, нет под рукой версии Community. Поэтому неизвестно, есть ли эта кнопка там или только в платных версиях Студии.

В комментариях выяснилось, что это полностью устраивает автора.

Однако, есть [сведения](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/446832/build-transform-all-t4-templates-not-working-for-d.html), что иногда это не работает, в частности, проблемы с .NET Core.
Также могут возникнуть [проблемы](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/324845/transform-all-t4-templates-not-working-after-updat.html) с конкретными платформами x64/x86, требуется указать Any CPU.

Answer (score 0):

**Можно получить ссылку на *EnvDTE* из стороннего приложения.**

[Объектная модель автоматизации Visual Studio. Интерфейсы EnvDTE](https://www.viva64.com/ru/b/0169/)

---

**DTE (Development Tools Environment)** переводится, как среда средств разработки.

Пара слов про `EnvDTE` / `EnvDTE80`. Если я правильно понял, то просто `EnvDTE` это базовый интерфейс. Далее `EnvDTE80` (соответствующий `VisualStudio.DTE.8.0`) расширяет просто `EnvDTE`, добавляя какой-то функционал. `EnvDTE100` (`VisualStudio.DTE.10.0`) расширяет `EnvDTE90` (`VisualStudio.DTE.9.0`).

---

Интерфейс `DTE` является абстракцией верхнего уровня для visual студии (в рамках [automation model](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/internals/automation-model-overview?view=vs-2019)). **Для того, чтобы получить на него ссылку из стороннего  приложения**, можно использовать ProgID COM identifier. Например, этот идентификатор для 2010 студии такой: "VisualStudio.DTE.10.0". Вот пример получения `DTE` из стороннего `c#`-ного приложения:

```
// Get the ProgID for DTE 8.0.
System.Type t = System.Type.GetTypeFromProgID(
    "VisualStudio.DTE.10.0", true);
// Create a new instance of the IDE.
object obj = System.Activator.CreateInstance(t, true);
// Cast the instance to DTE2 and assign to variable dte.
EnvDTE80.DTE2 dte = (EnvDTE80.DTE2)obj;
// Show IDE Main Window
dte.MainWindow.Activate();
```

Надо отметить, что создание экземпляра через `CreateInstance(...)` обозначает запуск `deven.exe`. Но само окно студии появится после запуска `Activate()`.

Но! **если студия уже запущена**, то можно так:

```
EnvDTE80.DTE2 dte2;
dte2 = (EnvDTE80.DTE2)
  System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject(
    "VisualStudio.DTE.10.0");
```

А **в случае нескольких запущенных студий** можно так:

```
using EnvDTE80;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes;

[DllImport("ole32.dll")]
private static extern void CreateBindCtx(int reserved, 
                                         out IBindCtx ppbc);
[DllImport("ole32.dll")]
private static extern void GetRunningObjectTable(int reserved, 
  out IRunningObjectTable prot);

public static DTE2 GetByID(int ID)
{
  //rot entry for visual studio running under current process.
  string rotEntry = String.Format("!VisualStudio.DTE.10.0:{0}", ID);
  IRunningObjectTable rot;
  GetRunningObjectTable(0, out rot);
  IEnumMoniker enumMoniker;
  rot.EnumRunning(out enumMoniker);
  enumMoniker.Reset();
  IntPtr fetched = IntPtr.Zero;
  IMoniker[] moniker = new IMoniker[1];
  while (enumMoniker.Next(1, moniker, fetched) == 0)
  {
    IBindCtx bindCtx;
    CreateBindCtx(0, out bindCtx);
    string displayName;
    moniker[0].GetDisplayName(bindCtx, null, out displayName);
    if (displayName == rotEntry)
    {
      object comObject;
      rot.GetObject(moniker[0], out comObject);
      return (EnvDTE80.DTE2)comObject;
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

Таким образом:

```
Process Devenv;
...
//Get DTE by Process ID
EnvDTE80.DTE2 dte2 = GetByID(Devenv.Id);
```

Далее, например, можно получить коллекцию проектов так:

```
Projects projects = (Projects)dte.GetObject("CSharpProjects");
```

---

Вот еще пара полезных статей:

[Creating EnvDTE.DTE for VS 2017 from outside the IDE](https://www.helixoft.com/blog/creating-envdte-dte-for-vs-2017-from-outside-of-the-devenv-exe.html)

[How to get DTE from Visual Studio process ID](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kirillosenkov/2011/08/10/how-to-get-dte-from-visual-studio-process-id/)